# Is there a way to re-review a suggested edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits

I was reviewing proposed edits when I accidentally bumped the mouse, causing it to click the "Approve" button. I was not going to approve the edit, because it slightly changed the question that was being asked. I was going to "Improve Edits" to keep some of the edits, but not all.

When I used the browser's back button to go back to the review, it showed that I had reviewed it and that other reviewer responses were required. However I could see no way to modify my review.

Is there a way to change my answer to the review, or is it permanent once entered?

Comment: Not that I know... Your only option to fix it is to wait for approval/rejection and edit yourself.

Comment: For the record, "Improve edit" approves the edit.  You should probably "Reject & edit" these bad edits, otherwise the users who suggest these will continue doing it.  It is the cause of a huge percentage of the incorrectly approved edits I see.

Comment: You could post the review link in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and type something like: `[tag:review-pls] Alters meaning of question, please reject, I misclicked and approved https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12345`. Then you could edit the question to fix the other issues you saw once the review task is completed.

Comment: Also, I dug up the post from your review history, rolled back the offending edit, and fixed the post's wording. Good catch on noticing that it changed the meaning of the post; I had to re-read the post several times to understand it.

Comment: You could edit the top revision of the post (via the post history page), that discards pending suggested edits.

Answer (score 2):

- In case your review approved the edit and no other reviews are required, simply go back to the post and do a rollback of the edit. Then optionally edit the post yourself after that.

  (Don't do a "rollback" by manual editing, use the rollback feature as step 1 and manual edit as step 2. Easier to read edit history that way.)
- In case the edit needs more reviews, I would do as advised in comments and visit the [SO close vote review chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask for help with rejecting the edit.
- As a last resort if everything else fails, flag the post with a custom flag and explain the situation to a moderator - provide a link to the suggested edit.