# How to change my suggested edit review

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I came across this question in the suggested edit review queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31658507

and approved the edit. Then I realized that there was an image that was not inlined and I tried to edit the question to fix it, but I was blocked because the edit (that I reviewed) needs more reviews from other users to be completed. How do I change my review so that I can inline the image in the question?

Comment: [Is there a way to re-review a proposed edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396263/15497888) / [Why can we not change our review choices?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400371/15497888) / [Can I change my review of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258820/15497888)

Comment: Given that it seems you were between "Approve" and "Improve edit" you could probably just wait. If the edit is approved you can make the additional one yourself afterward, which is basically what would've happened with the improve option. (Though I agree it would sometimes be nice to be able to make that fix without the delay) It's also possible another reviewer will feel similarly to you and take the opportunity to inline the image.

Comment: I took the opportunity to inline the image and approve the edit :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to change my suggested edit review

You **cannot** at the moment. Stack Exchange's review workflow does not support changing decisions made during review, even for a limited time afterwards. However, there are ways of correcting the mistake if you feel like you made one:

- drop by [Bad Stack Overflow Reviews](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/) chat room and ask for an override —   there is a high chance a moderator / active reviewer chances by your request and handles it;
- flag the post on which the suggested edit was made for moderator attention and explain the situation;
- create a Meta post about it (like you did here) if you are unsure of the correct action to take and want to get an opinion of the community at large first — as with the first option, a moderator or another reviewer might notice and handle the review;

Note that while a given review is just *pending*, the situation might still be sorted out by other reviewers, and you do not really have to do anything. For example, reviewers have the option to "improve" an edit, which allows them to build on top of your suggestion, fixing anything else you might have missed. However, as soon as the review item is complete, only moderators can override the decision (and only if there have not been any edits made since).

Comment: Waiting for review to finish and make the edit is another option that does not require outside help.

Comment: Following the post doesn't work, does it? (Because the notification would be for the edit being suggested, which already happened.)

Comment: @Laurel Wait, really? I would think if it was only going to notify you of one, either the suggestion or the edit actually being applied to the post, it would be the latter.